# Eloquent query builder replacement of and

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Hi I want to build query with eloquent.

DB name friends with 4 rows id,friend1, friend2 and accepted.

So I want to create something like this

> $count = Friends::where('friend1', '=', '$user1')->and('accepted', '=', '1')->orWhere('friend2', '=', '$user2')->and('accepted', '=', '1')->get();

Should I replace 'and' with 'where'. And if I do that it will work normally as with 'and'?

Comment: Using `where` implies `and` unless you explicitly use `orWhere`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a clear way of looking at it:

```
$count = Friends::where(function($query){
             $query->where('friend1', '=', '$user1')
                   ->where('accepted', '=', '1')
         })->orWhere(function($query){
             $query->where('friend2', '=', '$user2')
                   ->where('accepted', '=', '1')
         })->get();
```